# Customize default scripts generated by node init - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm searching all over the internet a way to add scripts in the dafault package.json made by npm init. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

your question is not clear but if i get it right , this is an example you have to add "scripts": {} to the packages.json ( if it's not already there ) and add your scripts in it .

`